# How to remove grey/black border of an UIPicker (iphone)

Tags: iphone, border, uipickerview, uipicker

I am using an UIpicker in a horizontal mode by rotating it 90 degrees.
I would like to get rid of the grey/black border surrounding the picker.
Is there a way to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt whether we can change the grey/black border surrounding the picker, we can modify the width and height.

Just a thought, Add a UIImageView in front of the UIPickerView which shows the border you need. If this has the problem of selection then add four images on the four side of the square.

Comment: hmm...quite a round about way I guess...I was hoping for something simpler:(

Comment: more easy way, write your custom UIPickerView.. :-)